# Adding EventHandler for WPF Title

Tags: c#, wpf

In WinForms I had the Event TextChanged for the form but in WPF it is missing.
How can I attach an EventHandler for the WPF Window Title ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind you Title to ViewModel-Proerty and observe it's changes via INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I want to add an if statement for the Title in OnPropertyChanged.
How can I get the Window Title here?  Thanks

Comment: Paste your code to the question. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mvvm/4293/getting-started-with-mvvm/15507/c-sharp-mvvm-summary-and-complete-example#t=201707241442315612584

Comment: Can't paste code here, it says it is too long. I will check out the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you won't do so. Add a property to your viewmodel for the title, and bind it. Thus you'll get notified when the title changes,